# How to replace last word of a pattern matched line based on delimiters in a Unix file?

Tags: unix

I have one file Backup_status.txt like below.

```
x01stestdb1a-10.92.201.111-SUCCESS
x01stestdb2a-10.92.201.112-SUCCESS
x01stestdb3a-10.92.201.113-SUCCESS
```

Backups running in all servers.

For ex, if backup filed in x01stestdb2a, we need to search with hostname x01stestdb2a in this file and change the status to FAIL.
Here i'm using hyphen(-) as delimiter.

Help me on how to search with that server name in the file and replace the last block using delimiter -.

NOTE: I want to change the content in the file.

Comment: use awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for help... if you already tried something, please add that to question, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: I tried some other ways as well, but not getting proper results. If anyone knows, please help me...

Comment: What were your results with `sed` or `ed` ?

Comment: I tried something like this, sed -i 's/`grep SERVER1`/FAIL/g' Backup_status.txt        But i'm not getting any thing.   Please help to solve this.

Comment: Does the delimiter matters here? `sed -i '/SERVER1/ s/SUCCESS/FAIL/' Backup_status.txt ` will change all the `SUCCESS` into `FAIL` on lines that contain `SERVER1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/SERVER1/ s/-[^-]*$/-FAIL/' Backup_status.txt
```

`/SERVER1/` let sed do the substitute on the line that matchs `SERVER1`.

The sed solution assume that the SUCCESS/FAIL is always in the last field, which may not be true. A more general solution is to use awk:

```
awk -i inplace -F'-'  '/SERVER1/ {sub($3, "FAIL")}; {print}' Backup_status.txt
```

- `-i inplace` is same as `sed -i`
- `-F'-'` set the delimiter to `'-'`
- `/SERVER1/ {sub($3, "FAIL")};` replace the third field of lines that contain `SERVER1` with "FAIL".
- `{print}` print each line. For lines that contain `SERVER1`, it'll print the changed version, otherwise it'll print the line as it is.

Comment: Actually this command replacing SUCCESS with FAIL. But my requirement is i don’t know earlier it was SUCCESS/FAIL. Whatever the earlier status no matter, i need to replace that with the current status. That’s why i’m concentrating on delimiter and trying to replace the 3rd field. Hope u got my requirement, if not please let me know. I will give example. Thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: Thank You very much for your time and help Dear...  This is working as expected.

Comment: I followed the same, i think there is some syntax error Bro.

Comment: I guess we use different version of awk. Mine is GNU Awk 4.2.0. You can adjust the command into your version, but the idea is the same.